# Reversing a large integer with trailing zeroes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse a large integer (>100 digits). I wish to implement it in such a way that the trailing zeroes in the original number are neglected. ie: reverse(2130200) gives 20312. My question is, how to implement reverse() in such a way that the trailing zeroes in the large integer are not added neglected. 
Eg: reverse(20301205500) gives 550210302

This is the code I implemented for small values.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int myreverse(int num)
{
    int rev=0;
    while(num)
    {
        rev=rev*10+(num%10);
        num/=10;
    }
    return rev;
}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    int a1 = myreverse(num);
    cout<<a1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int` can't hold a number with 100 digits. Why don't you operate on strings?

Comment: If it's over 100 digits, use a `std::string`, `std::reverse`, and `find_last_not_of`.

Comment: Thanks @chris! But I would like to implement the logic without just using 'reverse() method available in stl'.

Comment: Okay, then make your own `reverse` function taking those iterators and sub it in.

Comment: I need help in the same issue, regarding the implementation of the logic. I mean the basic approach.

Comment: Are you planning to do any arithmetic operations on this number after reversing it? If not, then as @chris has mentioned, you might as well use `std::string`. But if you **are** planning to perform arithmetic operations on it, then you'll need to use some sort of "BigInteger" class. You can see an example of such class in here: https://github.com/barakman/Num.

Comment: You are not ready to write `myreverse` yet.  As your question stands, `int num; cin>>num;` won't work with 100 digit integers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, i hope it will help you:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 1234567890;

    cout << "Number: " << number << endl;

    string str_of_number = to_string(number);

    string rvsd_str_of_number(str_of_number.rbegin(), str_of_number.rend());

    int rvsd_number = std::atoi(rvsd_str_of_number.c_str());

    cout << "Reversed number: " << rvsd_number << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Number: 1234567890
Reversed number: 987654321
```